# My threads seem to be hanging at the last couple of tasks (image downloads with requests)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm using threads to download images from the imagenetdata base.

Here is the link:
http://www.image-net.org/

First, I searched the imagenet database for **"puppies"** and I was able to get a textfile with 1000+ urls (urls for images)

(If you don't want to go that manner,

I've uploaded the urls onto this pastebin (first 400 or so):

https://pastebin.com/yTcHq0iw   )

I then read the first 200 lines of the textfile (thus 200 urls) and used
threads to download those 200 images.

If I download only 100 images (read only the first 100 urls), threads execute perfectly.
However If I try something like 150+ (150, 175,200 etc), the threads will download the first 147, (or 172ish if I'm using 175), and just hang for about 30 seconds or so, before finishing up the last few images.

I'm using Requests to download the images, so not sure if Requests is having trouble making some connections and that is the cause. I'm not too familiar with
Requests lower level API, so not sure how to fix it if it's a Request problem. I found some code on the internet and attempted to override some of the built-in options of Requests, but these tweaks haven't solved the "hanging" problem.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
import time
import queue
from threading import Thread




SAVE_DIR = r'C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\TEMP\Puppy_threading' #is a constant, 




def decorator_function(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        session = requests.Session()
        retry = Retry(connect=0, backoff_factor=0.2)
        adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
        session.mount('http://', adapter)
        session.mount('https://', adapter)

        return func(*args, session = session, **kwargs)
    return wrapper




#Using threading:
image_count = 0


#@decorator_function           (optional decorator_function)
def download_image(session = None):
        global image_count
        if not session:
                session = requests.Session()
        while not q.empty():

            try:
                    r = session.get(q.get(block = False))

            except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, UnicodeError) as e:
                print(e)
                image_count += 1
                q.task_done()
                continue

            image_count += 1
            q.task_done()

            print('image', image_count)
            with open(os.path.join(
                        SAVE_DIR, 'image_{}.jpg'.format(image_count)),
                        'wb') as f:

                f.write(r.content)



q =queue.Queue()
with open(r'C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\puppies.txt', 'rt') as f:
    for i in range(200):
        line = f.readline()
        q.put(line.strip())
print(q.qsize())


threads = []
start = time.time()
for i in range(50):
     t = Thread(target = download_image)
     t.setDaemon(True)
     threads.append(t)
     t.start()
q.join()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
    print(t.name, 'has joined')

end = time.time()
print('time taken: {:.4f}'.format(end - start))
```

Comment: create full working example or add `puppies.txt` so we could run it.

Comment: I want to add puppies.txt but where should I upload it? It's has a 1000+ urls, and when I asked where to upload it, the only response I get it to post the entire dataset in the post.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360682/where-should-i-upload-a-text-file-for-a-stackoverflow-post/360684#360684

Comment: @furas Okay, I uploaded the urls on pastebin. Thank you.

Comment: There seem to be many broken URLs there. Don’t you get errors printed to the console? The “hanging” you observe is probably just some of the servers timing out. Try adding `timeout=5` to your `session.get(...)` call and see if it finishes faster.

Comment: Yeah, I get the errors but I thought exceptions take care of those errors. However, for the last few images, I don't see any exception errors being printed to the console. I will try adding the timeout argument and report back. Thank you.

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov  You are right. If you write an answer I can accept. What is the default timeout value Requests uses? Thank you.